# Getting Connection Reset Issue while Fetching Azure Access Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

hope everyone is well.

I am using azure library to fetch access token using the below code snippet, but getting an error

```
Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
When I enclose the code in try catch, it gets catched as an ExecutionException.
```

Below is the code snippet.

```
ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder("XXX", ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(XXX, "")).authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX").build();
        

ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(String.format(https://graph.microsoft.com/.default))).build();


CompletableFuture future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);

//call to future.get() function
```

I appreciate if anyone could help me in this issue as I am unable to find any solution for this for the past 2 weeks, tried so many ways but no success.

Thanks

Comment: There is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/tree/master/msal-client-credential-certificate) to acquire the token and call the 
Graph API with MSAL. It seems that the code in your issue is correct. Please check the version in your pom.xml, and which line did you receive the error on?

Comment: i posted this on Microsoft forum also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/190104/getting-connection-reset-issue-while-fetching-azur.html